# How to give border/background to a Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, border, flutter-text

I want to give my text a border or background. Just a simple text in red with a black border around it.

See the following image as inspiration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html)

There's no border property but yes you can use two overlapping Texts to do the job. Here's the code

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // Stroked text as border.
    Text(
      'WHO',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        foreground: Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 6
          ..color = Colors.grey,
      ),
    ),
    // Solid text as fill.
    Text(
      'WHO',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look up the TextStyle class in the flutter Documentation. On Borders an Stroke you'll find your answer I believe.

[Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to `outlined_text` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/outlined_text)

You can also try this https://pub.dev/packages/bordered_text